# use perl to connect oracle with LDAP

Tags: linux, perl, ldap

I want to connect oracle db by perl with LDAP, but I got below issue:

No such database (dbase123456)! at /home/cy/scripts/test/lib/DBD/LDAP.pm line 401,  line 253.
DBI connect('dbase123456','cy',...) failed: No such database (dbase123456)! at ./test.pl line 28
Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at ./test.pl line 29,  line 253.

The perl scripst are:

```
my $query = GetQuery();

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:LDAP:dbase123456",'cy','cy');

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

$sth->execute();

my $rows_ = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

$sth->finish();
```

Please someone help me to check the root cause, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct db name? Because it clearly giving the **Database not found error**.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you haven't created the configuration file `dbase123456.ldb`

Take a look at [*GETTING STARTED* from the documentation for the `DBD::LDAP` driver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-LDAP/lib/DBD/LDAP.pm#GETTING_STARTED:)